# Geth losing transactions

Tags: transactions, nodes, geth-debugging

I have a couple of applications running on an Ethereum Blockchain hosted on a VM. For some reason, every now and then, I find my VM rebooted... so my blockchain is turned off...

There's no problem in restarting the chain again, but since the Blockchain is not halted carefully, I end up losing all transactions.

Is there something that I can do to address this issue? Periodically, I try to switch off / on the chain to minimise potential damage.

I am running Geth/PoA on a windows box.

Comment: What makes you think it's an issue with Geth? If the whole VM gets rebooted, it sounds like a VM issue.

Comment: i never said its a problem with geth. i am aware that its a vm issue. but as i have already said: "since the Blockchain is not halted carefully, I end up losing all transactions."
how can i avoid losing all transactions in the case of such a vm reboot?